# Theming and AppCompat

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am new to android and have theming question.

I have project using Toolbar with AppCompat-r21, for api 14+ devices.
Does this mean that only theme i can use is "Theme.AppCompat.Light"?

No Holo, no DeviceDefault ?

Comment: Holo and DeviceDefault (before Lollipop) doesn't have a concept of a Toolbar, nor the styling of Toolbars. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i don't really like AppCompat theme, so i want to use Holo. By the way does AppCompat theme is the Material theme?

Comment: If you're using a v21 support library, then the AppCompat theme tries to match Material as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbars are a concept only added as part of [material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/) - AppCompat is designed to bring [consistent design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) across all API versions, matching material design guidelines. Therefore if you want to use a Holo theme, you should stick to using the Holo [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) and not use Toolbars or AppCompat.

Note that your app will look considerably out of place on newer devices as well as not match any of the Google apps (which all use a material design styling even on older versions of Android).

Comment: Is there way to use AppCompat theme when device using pre Lollipop, and use Material when Lollipop+

Comment: That would defeat the entire purpose of AppCompat which is a consistent look across all platform levels.